# How to print the execution time of the computation done in a tensorflow code?

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is a generic question.

I wrote a piece of code that uses tensorflow to do the computation.

I want to print the time consumed during the execution of the code.

First I used:

```
import time
start = time.time()
main()
print ("%s"  % (time.time() - start_time))
```

But I read that this is an inaccurate way to measure the execution time.

How to accurately measure the execution time of my program.

Comment: If you use ipython you can run your code `%timeit main()`. Otherwise how long does your code take to run? If it's at least 1 second time.time() is okay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter). `perf_counter` is a "performance counter". It is the highest resolution time from an undefined starting point (Usually since the program started running) available on a platform. It is used for things measuring performance when subtracted from a subsequent call. It is a float in seconds.

[`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) is the seconds since the Unix epoch (1 January 1970), and may not be more precise than a second.

You can safely replace calls to `time.time()` with `time.perf_counter()`, as you are subtracting them.

```
import time
start = time.perf_counter()
main()
elapsed = time.perf_counter() - start
print('Elapsed %.3f seconds.' % elapsed)
# The .3f is to round to 3 decimal places.
```